# User Java Regex to extract data from String

Tags: java, regex

This is the input format:

```
<1> today is <2> current time is <3> humidity is <4>
```

I want to use Java Regex to get `<1>` ,`<2>`, `<3>` and `<4>`.

e.g if the input is

```
Hello today is 03/17 current time is 03:20 humidity is 50%
```

I want to get `Hello`, `03/17`, `03:20` and `50%`

Can anyone help show me what Regex should be?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Will the string always look like this? What's the maximum size of each field? There are more details needed for this.

Comment: @EvanKnowlesThanks Evan.  I have updated the question.

Comment: Is it a fixed pattern?

Comment: @sameerasy Yes, it's fixed pattern.  but value of <1>,<2>..<4> can be any string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

You can use a matcher with a regex to extract out the various pieces of the template input sentence which you expect.

```
String input = "Hello today is 03/17 current time is 03:20 humidity is 50%";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*) today is (.*) current time is (.*) humidity is (.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found greeting: " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Found date: " + m.group(2));
        System.out.println("Found time: " + m.group(3));
        System.out.println("Found humidity: " + m.group(4));
}
```

**Output:**

```
Found greeting: Hello
Found date: 03/17
Found time: 03:20
Found humidity: 50%
```

Note that capture groups begin at index 1, not 0, because `m.group(0)` returns the entire original string against which the regex is being applied.

Below is my original answer, which was given before you updated your question:

One simple approach would be to just split the sentence by whitespace, and then retain any terms which have at least one number in them:

```
String input = "Hello today is 01/17 current time is 03:20 humidity is 50%.";
String[] parts = input.split("\\s+");
for (String part : parts) {
    if (part.matches(".*\\d+.*")) {
        System.out.println(part);
    }
}
```